# Set a default value after the model was created in Waterline

Tags: sails.js, waterline

Is there a possibility to set a default value for an attribute after the model entity was created?

The attribute didn't exist before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [**defaultsTo**](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/attributes#?attribute-options).

> When a record is created, if no value was supplied, the record will be
>   created with the specified defaultsTo value. The supplied value can
>   also be a function that waterline will run while creating the record.

```
attributes: {
  phoneNumber: {
    type: 'string',
    defaultsTo: '111-222-3333'
  },
  orderNumber: {
    type: 'text',
    defaultsTo: function() {
      return uuid.v4();
    }
  }
}
```

You also may find [**Lifecycle callbacks**](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/lifecycle-callbacks) useful depending on your use-case.

> Lifecycle callbacks are functions that are automagically called before
>   or after certain model actions. For example, we sometimes use
>   lifecycle callbacks to automatically hash a password before creating
>   or updating an Account model.